# Break the 'scroll' event Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Now, I want to make fade from top effect when my element be in the viewport by adding 'activate' class for it...

I don't want to use any external libraries that do it direct.

My code is:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {

  var cards = document.querySelectorAll('cards');

  for ( let card of cards ) {
    if(!card.classList.contains('fadeFromTop')) {
      card.classList.add('fadeFromTop');
    }
  }

}
```

but when my element goes out from the viewport, it still checks if the element has that class

I didn't add the if statement that checks if the element is inside the viewport.

Is there a way to break and stop the scroll event when all cards have the class 'fadeFromTop' ?

I tried to search on google but what I find is the `element.removeEventListener();` and I can't understand what does it do...

Comment: Is not clear what you're asking. If you want to stop listening for the `scroll` event you can use `window.removeEventListener('scroll', this)`. Something like `if (cards.length === cards.querySelectorAll(".fadeFromTop").length) { window.removeEventListener('scroll', this) }`

Comment: like Titus said...you need an `if` call

Comment: ok I will give it a try